# How to implement and use shared function for different components

Tags: angular, function, service

On my homepage I have different HTML and components for the input and results of technical formular. As differ technical proposals.
 The binding of the properties (object with more properties) is done by `{{prop}}` in the HTML code and into the component class it is init by getter and setter method.

In an Angular service I like to have a mathematical function collection. This service is imported into the component.ts.

How to call that function and to pass the `{{prop}}` to the function and to get back the result?

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://angular.io/tutorial. You could use a pipe, for example, or call a method on the component. Also note you seem to have confused two-way binding and interpolation.

Comment: Refer to the pipes, I use them for input checks by onkeyup to ensure only numbers, commas and arrows key can be used. My problem is, that all description with services are more or less to GET data, e.g. from JSON files.

Comment: But I needs following:
@Component({...})
export class HomePageComponent {
X = new VariablenObjectService('A', 5);
Y = new VariablenObjectService('B', 2);

   constructor(private Func: FunctionsObjectService) { }
   ngOnInit() {}

     half(objX: VariablenObjectService, objY?: VariablenObjectService): void {this.Func.half(objX, objY ); }

Comment: __
@Injectable({...})
export class FunctionsObjectService {...

  in the service file:
half(x: VariablenObjectService, y?: VariablenObjectService) { x.wert = x.wert * 2; y.wert = y.wert / 2; }